# Return value ignored [scanf]

Tags: c

I'm using C language.
I know that every function has return value(except void function).
But C6031 warning message appears only in scanf function.
It doesn't appear in other functions like printf or hello (look below).
Why this Phenomenon happens?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int hello(void) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 10;
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is important not to ignore the return value of `scanf()` to check if it succeeded to read some data and not to cause unintended behavior by using uninitialized value.

Comment: It's also fairly important to check the value returned by `printf`, but most programs rely on a `printf` failure being accompanied by a SIGPIPE.   Most programmers are either happy with termination from SIGPIPE, don't know, or don't care.  When they run their code in some environment in which SIGPIPE is unexpectedly ignored (eg python subprocess), suddenly it becomes a problem.

Comment: If `printf` fails there is probably little remedial action you can take, but if `scanf` fails it is most likely from the user's faulty input, and the program will almost always need some remedial action (such as re-prompting). This makes checking `scanf` a vital part of the normal functionality.

Comment: As to the question of how does this work: It's likely that somewhere, perhaps in a header file like `<stdio.h>`, your environment is using some nonstandard mechanism to indicate which functions (like `printf`) can safely have their return values ignored, versus which functions (like `scanf`) should have this warned about.

Comment: I reopened this question because the duplicate answered the question "why is it dangerous to ignore the return value of scanf", but the actual question here is "why does this warning show up for some functions and not for others." That's probably a duplicate too, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3):

As @SteveSummit indicates in a comment, most C implementations have a mechanism to identify functions whose return value should not be ignored.

C itself (as defined by the C standard) has always allowed a caller to ignore the return value of a function. It even allows a function declared with a return value type to not return any value as long as all callers ignore the return value.

However, that permissiveness does not generally lead to good programming practice. In some cases, it is very likely that ignoring the return value of a function will lead to a bug. `scanf` is considered to be such a function, so the authors of standard libraries tend to mark `scanf` as requiring that the return value be used.

There is no standard way to mark a function as requiring use of their return values. In GCC and Clang, this is done using the attribute `warn_unused_result`:

```
int fn (int a) __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result));
```

(See the GCC documentation for [the `warn_unused_result` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-warn_005funused_005fresult-function-attribute) and how to turn off the warning (not recommended): [the `-Wno-unused-result](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-result).)

In MSVC, it's done with the `_Check_return_` macro, found in `sal.h`:

```
#include <sal.h>
_Check_return_ int fn (int a);
```

(See [the Visual Studio docs for error C6031](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6031?view=msvc-160) and [this documenation on the Source Annotation Library (sal)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=msvc-160).)

There are good reasons not to ignore the return value of any library function which uses the return value to indicate failure, including many standard library functions which do input or output. Ignoring input or output failure can lead to problems, but the problems are more evident when ignoring input failure because that can lead to the use of uninitialised values, which in turn can lead to Undefined Behaviour. That is certainly the case for `scanf`: ignoring its return value means that your program will not respond correctly to malformed input, which is almost certainly a bug.

Ignoring the failure of output functions will sometimes mean that the user is not warned about failure to save persistent data. That can be serious, and it may well be that some action needs to be taken to save that data. But in other cases, the error simply means that the user didn't see some logging message and most likely will not see future logging messages either. This might not be considered important.

Answer (score 0):

put scanf inside an if.

scanf returns the number of successfully input parameter.

```
if(scanf("%d", &i)) {};
```

Comment: But you haven't addressed the point about why the warning isn't issued for the `hello()` call.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.